# Reach middle element on (window).scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, offset

I don't know what is going wrong?
I was trying all to get the #second element when scroll

Here's example with console.log
[CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/SzymonDziewonski/pen/aCuJt)

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var section     =     $("#second").offset().left,
    scrollXpos          =   $("body").scrollLeft();




    if(scrollXpos == section){

        console.log("second")
    }
    else{
         console.log("rest")
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand, the code is straight forward and it works as expected. What's the issue? Edit: Are you scrolling using the scroll buttons in the browser window? If so, the scroll speed set my the browser or user's options may completely miss the event because it will skip the area where the event should be triggered.

Comment: actually it doesnt work thats why im asking for help. W8 a moment ill do file on my server to show what doesnt work.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Ok heres link: http://revelier.home.pl/window/  and now when u scroll doesnt matter how (by scrollwheel or arrows or scrollbar) when reach #second should append on #prove "working" but its not. I have no idea why, code should work and yet its not. Any other methods?

Comment: It works for me. It might be your browser. When I scroll towards the middle and get to the #second element, it appends "working" to "not working".

Comment: chrome, but i tested it in all browsers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35653/discussion-between-szymon-dziewonski-and-trendy)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently opera , ie and firefox works better with

```
$(document).scrollLeft();
```

not

```
$("body").scrollLeft();
```

and same goes for

```
$(document, window).scroll(function(){
```

not

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
```

Thx @trendy